# Trigonometry: Reversal of reciprocal identities?

Tags: trigonometry

Does $\frac{1}{\sec^2 x} = \cos^2 x$? I am new to trigonometric identities, and have not yet seen this question appear.

Comment: Yes. This is more of an algebra question as long as you know the definition of $\sec(x)$. Hint: $$\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$$

Comment: Of course except when $\sec x$ is undefined and $\cos x = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the definition (see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Secant.html) of the secant function (and taking a square). So you dont really need any trigonometry at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true from the definition of $\sec x$, which is:

$$\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$$
Square this and take the reciprocal of both sides and you obtain your expression.